# perl formatting question

Tags: perl

What does this formattin string mean in perl

```
sprintf "%014ld", "$variable";
```

Comment: 8 questions, 0 accepts? Pass.

Comment: Have you, like, tried reading [the fine manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means "assume $variable is a long integer (64 bits) and print it zero-padded to 14 digits width."

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html for an explanation of all the possible printf formatting arguments.

Comment: Sure, use format() on the String class.  It was introduced in 1.5: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Answer (score 3):

It prints a long integer (`ld`). The resulting number will be padded with leading zeros (`0`) until 14 characters (`14`) are reached.